# Prolog inserting values from a list into another list

Tags: prolog

I want to insert my `ligacao` and `cidade` parameters into a list that contains vias.

My ligacao and cidade facts are

```
ligacao(porto,braga,comboio,35,1500,1600,5).

cidade(sevilha,espanha,60,interior).

biarc(X,Y,D,Custo,Hi,Hf) :- ligacao(X,Y,_,D,A,B,Custo),Hi=A,Hf=B.
```

The next functions are

```
conc([], L, L).
conc([C|R], L, [C|T]) :- conc(R, L, T).

addcond_tem(CA, via(P1,P2,Custo,Reg1,Reg2),CN) :- not(member(via(P1,P2,_,_,_),CA)), not(member(via(P2,P1,_,_,_),CA)), conc(CA,[via(P1,P2,Custo,Reg1,Reg2)],CN).

path_tem(X,Y,C,Horaini,Horafin) :- step_tem(X,Y,[],C,Horaini,Horafin).

step_tem(PC,PD,CA,CT,Hi,Hf) :- biarc(PC,PD,_,Custo,A,B),A>=Hi,B=<Hf, tirar_regioes(PC,PD,Reg1,Reg2),addcond_tem(CA, via(PC,PD,Custo,Reg1,Reg2),CT).
step_tem(PC,PD,CA,CT,Hi,Hf) :- biarc(PC,PN,_,Custo,A,B),A>=Hi,B=<Hf,tirar_regioes(PC,PN,Reg1,Reg2), addcond_tem(CA, via(PC,PN,Custo,Reg1,Reg2),Ci), step_tem(PN,PD,Ci,CT,Hi,Hf).

tirar_regioes(PC,PD,Reg1,Reg2):-cidade(PC,_,_,Reg1),cidade(PD,_,_,Reg2).
```

But when I test :

```
?-path_tem(porto,faro,C,600,2000).
false
```

I can't seem to get via`(A,B,C,D,E,F)` and it gives me false.

If i only one Reg1 and don't use Reg2 with the proper modificatioons it goes well. Can't I use both `cidade(PC,_,_,_)` and `cidade(PD,_,_,_`) in the same function?

If I do this:

```
addcond_tem(CA, via(P1,P2,Custo,Reg1),CN) :- not(member(via(P1,P2,_,_),CA)), not(member(via(P2,P1,_,_),CA)), conc(CA,[via(P1,P2,Custo,Reg1)],CN).

path_tem(X,Y,C,Horaini,Horafin) :- step_tem(X,Y,[],C,Horaini,Horafin).

step_tem(PC,PD,CA,CT,Hi,Hf) :- biarc(PC,PD,_,Custo,A,B),A>=Hi,B=<Hf, cidade(PC,_,_,Reg1),addcond_tem(CA, via(PC,PD,Custo,Reg1),CT).
step_tem(PC,PD,CA,CT,Hi,Hf) :- biarc(PC,PN,_,Custo,A,B),A>=Hi,B=<Hf,cidade(PC,_,_,Reg1), addcond_tem(CA, via(PC,PN,Custo,Reg1),Ci), step_tem(PN,PD,Ci,CT,Hi,Hf).
```

It works. I don't understand why it works this way and the other it doens't.

Comment: It is nice that you post so much code. But I can not understand the words so it is hard for me to understand what is going on. 1. Can you produce a minimal example? 2. `?- path` or `?- path_tem`?

Comment: Sorry. Where i put path i meant path_tem. Do you want me to show you how i wanted it to work?

Comment: That would also be helpful.

Comment: The last path_tem example gives me something like this:
`A = [via(porto, braga, 5,litoral), via(braga, guimaraes, 9,neve), via(guimaraes, alverca, 7,litoral), via(alverca, faro, 10,montanha)] ;`

I wanted my path_tem to give me something like this:
`A = [via(porto, braga, 5,litoral,neve), via(braga, guimaraes, 9,neve,montanha), via(guimaraes, alverca, 7,litoral,litoral), via(alverca, faro, 10,montanha,litoral)] ;`

Comment: Have you tried using `?- gtrace, path_tem(porto,faro,C,600,2000)`?

Comment: God bless you. I had one parameter mispelled in the facts... it already worked. Everything seems to be fine now. Thank you